# Which settings make vim a convenient email editor?

Tags: email, vim, settings, composition

Claws-mail is my email client and it can launch an external editor when you compose an email. And in general I prefer to use vim as my editor. But with emails I can't find convenient settings.

I want vim to auto wrap lines that exceed 76 characters, but not always, for example if I make an (un)ordered list. I suppose vim can be the most convenient editor out there. So far I only know about the `textwidth`, the `gqip` keys to format a paragraph, and the `:set formatoption+=a` option. I'm a bit confused about the other formatoption settings. So I turn to you and ask:

Which settings will make vim a great email editor?

Comment: I suggest you stick to a specific question if you have one, e.g. "How do I do *X* in vim?" This seems like a pretty vague question and I think will likely be closed.

Comment: This question, as it stands, is likely to get closed soon. If it does, and you still wish it answered, reformat the question so it concentrates on your issues with formatting. "Which settings will make Vim a great mail editor" is a topic too vague for this site, and it depends entirely on one person to another.